# Making button enabled when javascript return true

Tags: javascript, html, forms, captcha

I'm trying to do a form with a basic captcha. Currently, because I'm a novice HTML coder, I only did the submit button enabled when the user clicks the verify button (it doesn'T enable itself when it sees return true.) And I'm trying to make it so if it returns `return true` i want to make the button enabled, and disabled at other times. Here is the link to the code: https://codepen.io/pen/GRpVmve

I would appreciate if anyone helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove button verify button and add to input oninput function

```js
function Check(){
  document.getElementById("button2").disabled = true;
  if(ValidCaptcha()){     
    document.getElementById("button2").disabled = false; 
  }
}


function Captcha(){
   var alpha = new Array('a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z');
   var i;
   for (i=0;i<6;i++){
     var a = alpha[Math.floor(Math.random() * alpha.length)];
     var b = alpha[Math.floor(Math.random() * alpha.length)];
     var c = alpha[Math.floor(Math.random() * alpha.length)];
     var d = alpha[Math.floor(Math.random() * alpha.length)];
     var e = alpha[Math.floor(Math.random() * alpha.length)];
     var f = alpha[Math.floor(Math.random() * alpha.length)];
     var g = alpha[Math.floor(Math.random() * alpha.length)];
    }
  var code = a + ' ' + b + ' ' + ' ' + c + ' ' + d + ' ' + e + ' '+ f + ' ' + g;
  document.getElementById("mainCaptcha").value = code;
 Check()
}
function ValidCaptcha(){
    var string1 = removeSpaces(document.getElementById('mainCaptcha').value);
    var string2 = removeSpaces(document.getElementById('txtInput').value);
    if (string1 == string2){
      return true;
    }
    else{        
      return false;
    }
}
function removeSpaces(string){
  return string.split(' ').join('');
}
```

```html
<form action="https://www.w3schools.com/action_page.php">
  <label for="fname">First name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" value="John"><br>
  <label for="lname">Last name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" value="Doe"><br><br>
  <h3>Gender</h3>
    <input type="radio" id="male" name="gender" value="male">

  <label for="male">Male</label><br>
  <input type="radio" id="female" name="gender" value="female">
  <label for="female">Female</label><br>
  <input type="radio" id="other" name="gender" value="other">
  <label for="other">Other</label>

     <body onload="Captcha();">
        <table>
          <tr>
           <h3>
                 Captcha<br />
           </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
           <td>
             <input type="text" id="mainCaptcha" disabled/>
              <input type="button" id="refresh" value="Refresh" onclick="Captcha();" />
           </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
           <td>
              <input type="text"oninput="Check()" name="captcha" id="txtInput"/>   
          </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
          <td>
            
              <input type="submit" id="button2" value="Send" disabled>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </body>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work for you...

```js
window.onload=()=>{
  document.getElementById('button2').disabled = true;
  let text = document.getElementById('txtInput').value;
 Captcha();
}

function Captcha(){
var alpha = new Array('a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z');
for (i=0;i<6;i++){
   var a = alpha[Math.floor(Math.random() * alpha.length)];
   var b = alpha[Math.floor(Math.random() * alpha.length)];
   var c = alpha[Math.floor(Math.random() * alpha.length)];
   var d = alpha[Math.floor(Math.random() * alpha.length)];
   var e = alpha[Math.floor(Math.random() * alpha.length)];
   var f = alpha[Math.floor(Math.random() * alpha.length)];
   var g = alpha[Math.floor(Math.random() * alpha.length)];
}
var code = a + ' ' + b + ' ' + ' ' + c + ' ' + d + ' ' + e + ' '+ f + ' ' + g;
 document.getElementById("mainCaptcha").value = code
 }

function ValidCaptcha(){
var string1 = removeSpaces(document.getElementById('mainCaptcha').value);
var string2 = removeSpaces(document.getElementById('txtInput').value);
if (string1 == string2){
  document.getElementById('button2').disabled = false;
}                      
else{      
 document.getElementById('button2').disabled = true;
}
}
function removeSpaces(string){
  return string.split(' ').join('');
}
function check(x){
  if(x.length<7 || x.length>7){
     document.getElementById('button2').disabled = true;
  }
}
```

```html
<form action="https://www.w3schools.com/action_page.php">
  <label for="fname">First name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" value="John"><br>
  <label for="lname">Last name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" value="Doe"><br><br>
  <h3>Gender</h3>
    <input type="radio" id="male" name="gender" value="male">

  <label for="male">Male</label><br>
  <input type="radio" id="female" name="gender" value="female">
  <label for="female">Female</label><br>
  <input type="radio" id="other" name="gender" value="other">
  <label for="other">Other</label>

     <body onload="Captcha();">
        <table>
          <tr>
           <h3>
                 Captcha<br />
           </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
           <td>
             <input type="text" id="mainCaptcha" disabled/>
              <input type="button" id="refresh" value="Refresh" onclick="Captcha();" />
           </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
           <td>
            <input type="text" id="txtInput" onkeyup="check(this.value)"/>
          </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
          <td>
              <input id="button1" type="button" value="Verify" onclick="ValidCaptcha()">
              <input type="submit" id="button2" value="Send">
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </body>

</form>
```

Comment: Hi, I tried your code but I noticed that users can just click the send button without clicking the verify button because it is enabled when the page opens. But thanks for the answer.